# Exception from Tracker recompute function, RangeError: Invalid time value | react, meteor,

Tags: reactjs, date-fns

I'm getting an error saying `Exception from Tracker recompute function` and `RangeError: Invalid time value`.

The problem is sometime the `card` gets `undefined` and since it is undefined, I can't run this : `const dateFormat = isThisYear(createdAt) ? "MMM d" : "MMM d, yyyy";`

Is there a way to execute `dateFormat` only when the card has value?

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import { format, isThisYear } from "date-fns";

const Sample = ({ card }) => {
  const { createdAt, title } = card || {};

  const dateFormat = isThisYear(createdAt) ? "MMM d" : "MMM d, yyyy";
  const createdDate = format(createdAt, dateFormat);

  return (
    <>
      <Child createdDate={createdDate} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Sample;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a necessarily a Meteor.js question , but more of a vanilla javascript question , you should check for truthiness of your variables before returning them . createdAt and(or) title in this case .
I might approach you situation as below .

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";
import { format, isThisYear } from "date-fns";
  
const Sample = ({ card }) => {
  const { createdAt, title } = card || {};
  if (createdAt) {
    const dateFormat = isThisYear(createdAt) ? "MMM d" : "MMM d, yyyy";
    const createdDate = format(createdAt, dateFormat);
  }
  if (createdDate) {
    return (
     <>
       <Child createdDate={createdDate} />
     </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
     <>
       <Child createdDate={} />
     </>
    );   
  }
};
  
export default Sample;
```